# Call Activity by items in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am building an application for android and I am not able to make that when I click on an item inside my Navigation drawer it opens a new activity pre established by me. can you help me?

I already tried some code using intents but when I click on the item it ends up closing the application.

```
case R.id.homepage: {

            homepage();
            break;
        }

        case R.id.pdefault: {
            testdefault();
            break;
        }



private void homepage(){
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class));
}

private void testdefault(){

    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),testdefault.class));
}
```

The first case worked normally because I created a method for
start the activity, but I did the same for the second and it did not work.

The expected result is just a simple screen swap.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the activity? That name is not possible.

I recommend you to use right click - new - activity - empty activity. That will create the structure needed to recognize it as an activity.

Take into account that if you create it manually you will have to override from AppCompatActivity and declare the activity in the manifest as:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity" />
```

It is not just creating a class. Make sure not to use underscores for activity names, keep the format of MainActivity